# How to reference a static resource from within a datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

I have the following problem:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OrganisationsItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoadSpacesCommand, ElementName=OrganisationList}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Padding="-5,0,-5,-5" Margin="-7,-12,-7,-7" Height="auto" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="True" FontSize="0.01">
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="67"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <Image Source="{Binding image.thumbnail_link}" Width="62" Height="62"></Image>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" />-->
                            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="SpacesList"
                                        Background="Transparent"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SpacesTemplate }" 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding spaces}" 
                                        Margin="40,0,0,96" 
                                        LayoutMode="List"
                                        HideEmptyGroups="True"
                                        IsGroupingEnabled="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                            </phone:LongListSelector>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SpacesTemplate">
            <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5,0,0,5">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Width="62" 
         Height="62" Margin="0,0,18,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

In my data template I am placing LongListselector... which also needs a template. but the SpacesTemplate that is defined outside the current datatemplate cannot be seen. any ideas how to reference the datatemplate "SpacesTemplate" from within the datatemplate "OrganisationsItemTemplate"

Comment: ahh, my apologies. I think this works fine.. it's actually the fact that the list is leaking the boundaries of the phone.. I wasn't reading the error... or not. does the above look right or wrong? Its hard to tell if it's the error or not?

Comment: Xaml is read top down, if you want to use `SpacesTemplate` inside `OrganisationsItemTemplate` you will have to put `SpacesTemplate` before `OrganisationsItemTemplate` in the Xaml

Comment: that's the answer. nice one dude. glad  didn't delete my question in the end! cool thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xaml` is read top down, if you want to use `SpacesTemplate` inside `OrganisationsItemTemplate` you will have to put `SpacesTemplate` before `OrganisationsItemTemplate` in the `Xaml`

Comment: side note, is the drilldown of data okay? if my parent datatemplate is using "Organisations" and accessing a name property inside of it.. if I then in the second LongListSelector put the datasource as spaces... that will be accessing the spaces list inside the Organisations object and that is a list which has "name" property in it. that sounds alright doesn't it... It's just my jump list just seems to flatten out, I guess because it doesn't have data to push the bits down.